# Feedly.com development and feed parser

Tags: rss, feed, feedparser, feedly

Is http://feedly.com built using PHP, Java, or some other language/framework?

I have googled for some information on it, and saw that it uses JSON/REST extensively. But, I am not sure as to what feed parser is used to render images and videos into the application so elegantly, ie:

[image]
<sub>(source: [lifeinthefastlane.com](http://lifeinthefastlane.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/feedly_003.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Well, it's running tomcat. So my guess is java. But this question is not appropriate here, IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this about the feed parser, or the rendering? At any rate, the feed parser is google's, and likely derived from the eponymous python package. The rendering is client-side javascript. This is a very cost-efficient, stateless architecture.

Answer (score 0):

After more research, I found out that feedly's CEO commented on their blog ( http://blog.feedly.com/2009/03/03/jsonrest-vs-xmlsoap/ ) and stated that:

> Although JSON works indeed very well
>   in Javascript application, it works
>   equally well **on the server side (our
>   back-end is entirely implemented in
>   Java using MySQL and Memcached through
>   hibernate**). JSON is just a very simple
>   and efficient way of representing data
>   structure. Based on my experience
>   5-10% of applications really need the
>   complexity/composition complexity of
>   XML+XML schema. Of the rest, I think
>   that JSON gives you the same value
>   with a lot less complexity and more
>   efficiency.